# Interpreter semantics: clarifying the steps an interpreter makes

Tags: interpreter, semantics, bytecode

This question is about definitions, semantics.

I understand the general concept of interpretation, translating source to machine code in real-time, or into an intermediate cache which is later "compiled" in real time or just before run time, etc.

Is there a **semantic** distinction made between the source > byte code translation step, and the byte code > machine code translation step?  Do people typically refer to the first part as "interpretation" and the second step as "compilation".  Please don't misunderstand, I am not asking for a definition of compilation outside the scope of **dynamic languages**.  That is another topic.

Additionally, is it futile to make a semantic distinction between these two steps, due to the large number of interpreters that implement so many different techniques?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, interpretation means the execution of a program in an arbitrary form (plain sourcecode, abstract syntax tree (AST), bytecode, ...) by an interpreter.

Some virtual machines make heavy use of JITs (just in time compilers) which translate (compile) the intermediate representation of a program to native machine code. This is definitely a form of compilation.

Also, some VMs do several phases of compilation: At first, an AST is compiled to bytecode, which can later on be compiled to machine code.

I would say, compilation means basically a transformation of one intermediate representation to the next representation.

Comment: Good enough.  But you've brought up virtual machines, from what I understand it's necessary for the virtual machine to exist, as the byte code instructions are coded to them.  But do the VMs typically handle the source > byte code step as well?  I'm guessing it depends largely on implementation?

Comment: Well, it depends whether one regards the parser, which does the [SOURCE > INTERMEDIATE] step, as part of the VM or not.

Comment: Ah parser, that's the word I was hoping existed, thanks!  Is there a similar term for the part of the interpreter that is not the parser (or comes after the parser is run?)

Comment: Well, that would be the interpreter / the compiler, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

The steps an interpreter makes is usually programmed in a loop similar to:

```
get next instruction
parse and interpret its components
dispatch its translation
```

The definitions and semantics of the language are only implemented in an interpreter, but are defined elsewhere.

The answer to your question lies in the formal, operational and axiomatic semantic definitions of the language being either interpreted or compiled.  In both cases, the semantics of the formal language definition must be preserved and consistent for any interpretation or compilation regardless of the implementation techniques employed.

Implementations of languages such as interpreters and compilers are tested against test suites which test the implementation of each language construct in the language against its formal semantic definition.

A language designer generates the formal definition of a language in a symbolic form such as denotational semantics.  This definition is very abstract from a mathematical point-of-view.

A compiler or interpreter implementer is more interested in the operational semantic definition of the language which is more directly related to building the compiler or interpreter to run on a target machine.

A user of the language is more interested in the axiomatic definition of the language which informs programmers how to use the language's constructs to create programs.